# Protobuf version incompatibility with Spring Cloud Hoxton.SR5

Tags: spring-boot, protocol-buffers, spring-cloud

I am migrating my old SpringBoot application from `SB-2.0 to SB-2.3`. I was getting a version issues due spring cloud (old pom has `Finchley.RELEASE`). Changed it to use `Hoxton.SR5` (as this is the compatible version with `SB-2.3`). But now I am getting issue because of `protobuf`.

While building it tries to get version `3.11.4` for `protobuf` but in my local I have `2.5.0`.
It looks like `Hoxton.SR5` internally uses/forces to use `3.11.4`. I can obviously change to `3.11.4` but want to know if my understanding of the issue is correct or there is more to it that I am not understanding here.

```
[INFO] Protobuf dependency version 3.11.4
[INFO] 'protoc' executable version 2.5.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  6.308 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-07-09T22:17:19+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.igor-petruk.protobuf:protobuf-maven-plugin:0.6.3:run (default) on project TestProject: Protobuf installation version does not match Protobuf library version -> [Help 1]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem, it's probably due to some transitive dependency from Spring Cloud Open Feign, since, as you can see here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/blob/2.2.x/spring-cloud-openfeign-core/pom.xml#L225 It was necessary to set up 3.14.0 for the tests, meaning that one of its dependencies is probably using that version.

As always, if you want to override the version from a transitive dependency by one of your own choosing, just add it in the Dependency Management, like this:

```
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
                <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```